# Better way to read nextLine

Tags: java

Working through a HackerRank tutorial, and I was wondering -- is there a better way to strip off the newline character that comes after reading in the double? It feels really manual and "hacky" to just repeat a `nextLine()`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = scan.nextInt();
    double d = scan.nextDouble();
    String b = scan.nextLine();
    String s = scan.nextLine();
}
```

}

Note: code works as-is, just asking if there is a less hacky way to go about this

Comment: I don't see an extra `nextLine()` in your code.

Comment: Whoops, I should have clarified -- `String b` isn't actually being used other than for the Scanner to pass over the newline char after it reads in the preceding double.

Comment: Then don't create a variable. Just call the method.

Comment: Look at @berdario's answer in possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operate on lines at a time, then you don't need to worry about the `nextDouble()` (or `nextInt()`) calls leaving a trailing newline. Like,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
double d = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
String s = scan.nextLine();
```

**If**, you want to allow the `int` and `double` to be on the same line then you could do

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = scan.nextInt();
double d = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
String s = scan.nextLine();
```

But without knowing your input format, that may or not be helpful. I would *prefer* the version most readable for the problem at hand (*parsing* the input).

Comment: `int i = scan.nextInt()` The integer may be on the same line as the double. `123  2.3`

Comment: Excellent, this is **exactly** what I was looking for. Thank you! Marking as answer.

Comment: @donkon In which case, you could use a `split("\\s+")` and parse it; or use a parser generator if you need a more formal grammar.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That's a lot of code. All you have to do is change the `int i =` line. The rest can stay.